# Error running .jar on a Mac

Tags: java, macos, jar, terminal, noclassdeffounderror

I have 2 files, Project.jar and JavaFile.java, saved in a folder called Project.  I compiled them both successfully using Mac's Terminal as per below:

```
 javac -cp Project.jar JavaFile.java
```

However, after trying to run the program, which is supposed to receive 2 arguments, using

```
 java -cp Project.jar JavaFile argument1 argument2
```

I get the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: JavaFile
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: JavaFile
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

I'm very new to Java and any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you already try with "Project.jar"?

Comment: I don't believe that's what you're running. Please provide a complete example reproducing this behavior.

Comment: Ignoring my answer below, let's try one more thing; did you tried to add current directory to class-path as well? I.e. java -cp .:Program.jar JavaFile arg1 arg2 ?

Comment: @kwoxer sorry, not sure what you mean?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I have tried again and got a slightly different message, please see my original post above.

Comment: @MiroslavHudak  I tried this, not working unfortunately...

Comment: Is your `JavaFile` class in a package?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis No, it's not.  Also, it is worth to mention that I have managed to run it in Windows and the problem occurs only when I try to run it in Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I figured it out... I need to use colon in order to separate the elements:

```
javac -cp "Project.jar:" JavaFile.java

java -cp "Project.jar:" JavaFile
```